# SharePoint: Perform a query to load data into external list and display the results in a list within the webpart

Tags: web-part, sql-server, external-content-type, bdc-model

I am relatively new to coding and I am trying to complete a project in Sharepoint. I have a webpart which includes Peoplepicker. When the submit button is pressed the first username passed is used as a parameter for a ReadList method to populate an external list. Now, how do you do display this data within the webpart? I tried adding a separate webpart that pulls the info from the external list, however it look like it reperforms the query with no parameters and so nothing is displayed cause the list becomes empty.

here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;

using Microsoft.SharePoint.BusinessData.SharedService;
using Microsoft.BusinessData.MetadataModel;
using Microsoft.BusinessData.Runtime;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;

using Microsoft.BusinessData.Infrastructure;
using Microsoft.BusinessData.MetadataModel.Collections;
using System.Drawing;

namespace RadiologyDatabase.UserPickerAndRecords
{
    [ToolboxItemAttribute(false)]
    public partial class UserPickerAndRecords : WebPart
    {
        // Uncomment the following SecurityPermission attribute only when doing Performance Profiling on a farm solution
        // using the Instrumentation method, and then remove the SecurityPermission attribute when the code is ready
        // for production. Because the SecurityPermission attribute bypasses the security check for callers of
        // your constructor, it's not recommended for production purposes.
        // [System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Assert, UnmanagedCode = true)]
        public UserPickerAndRecords()
        {
        }

        protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnInit(e);
            InitializeControl();
        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
        protected void people_and_records(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string allPeople = peoplepicker.CommaSeparatedAccounts;
            string[] selected = allPeople.Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            foreach (string p in selected)
            {
                string person =p.Substring(13);
                selectedPeople.Items.Add(person);
            }
//make sure that some user id actually got retrieved
            if (selectedPeople.Items.Count != 0)
            {
                //retrieve the key records for that user id
                string username = selectedPeople.Items[0].ToString();
                selectedPeople.Items.Add(username);

                try {
                    using (new Microsoft.SharePoint.SPServiceContextScope(SPServiceContext.GetContext(SPContext.Current.Site)))
                        {
                        // Get the BDC service and metadata catalog.
                         BdcService service = SPFarm.Local.Services.GetValue<BdcService>(String.Empty);
                         IMetadataCatalog catalog = service.GetDatabaseBackedMetadataCatalog(SPServiceContext.Current); 
                        // Get the entity by using the specified name and namespace.
                         IEntity entity = catalog.GetEntity("RadiologyDatabase.SQLDataConnection", "userKeyRecordEntity");
                         ILobSystemInstance lobSystemInstance = entity.GetLobSystem().GetLobSystemInstances()[0].Value;

                         // Create an Identity
                         Identity identity = new Identity(username);

                         // Get a method instance for the SpecificFinder method.
                         IMethodInstance method = entity.GetMethodInstance("ReadList",MethodInstanceType.Finder);
                         IParameterCollection parameters = method.GetMethod().GetParameters();
                         //Set Parameters
                         System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("this is a test2: + " + username);
                         object[] arguments = new object[parameters.Count];

                         System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("this is a test4: + " + parameters.Count);

                         arguments[0] = username;
                         arguments[1] = username;

                         System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("this is a test3: + " + arguments[0]);
                         entity.Execute(method, lobSystemInstance, ref arguments);
                        }
                    }         
                catch (Exception ex){
                    StatusLabel.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                    StatusLabel.Text = "Unable to create customer." +
                    ex.Message;
                }
               }
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: You want external list data to be displayed on Webpart?

Comment: Well yes. Once the external list is populated through the query I would like to grab all of its contents and display them in a list within a webpart.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Sharepoint server object model to get data from External list:

```
SPSite oSpSite = new SPSite("http://spdevserver:1002/");
SPWeb oSPWeb = oSpSite.OpenWeb();
SPList oSpList = oSPWeb.Lists["Products"];
SPListItemCollection oSpListCln = oSpList.Items;
foreach (SPListItem item in oSpListCln)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item["Product Name"] + "\n");
}
```

In this way you can read the data and display in anywhere you want.